# Finding a PDE with Random Walks

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, random-walk

I have a question about Random Walks, but am confused by the question. So, the question is:

> Given the Probabilistic Equation:
>   $$p(x,t+\Delta t)=\frac{p(x+\Delta x,t)+p(x-\Delta x,t)}{2}$$
>   Find the PDE for the 2 cases:$$$$
>   a) If $\Delta x\rightarrow 0$, then $$\frac{(\Delta x)^2}{\Delta t}=4$$
>   b) If $\Delta x\rightarrow 0$, then $$\frac{(\Delta x)^3}{\Delta t}=4$$

Now I solved $(a)$, by subtracting $p(x,t)$ from both sides, dividing by $\Delta t$, and multiplying the right hand side by $1=\frac{(\Delta x)^2}{(\Delta x)^2}$ to get:
$$\frac{p(x,t+\Delta t)-p(x,t)}{\Delta t} = \frac{(\Delta x)^2}{2\Delta t}\left(\frac{p(x+\Delta x,t)+p(x-\Delta x,t)-2p(x,t)}{(\Delta x)^2}\right)$$
As we take $\Delta t\rightarrow 0, \>\>\Delta x\rightarrow 0$, we have that the above becomes:
$$p_t = 2p_{xx}$$
But I have no idea how to do $(b)$. I tried using the third order approximation of the derivative, which can be done to the right hand side, but it doesn't add up on the left hand side. If anyone could give me a hint about this question it would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The diffusion coefficient becomes $2/\Delta x$ as $\Delta x \to 0$. So I think you would get infinitely fast diffusion, i.e., $p(x,t)$ is a constant for all time equal to the average at time zero.

Comment: Actually it may be affine. Taylor expand both sides and equate highest order terms you should get $\rho_{xx}=0$ for the second case.

Comment: @Jeff I'm confused by what you mean? How can I Taylor Expand the right hand side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taylor expand both sides:
$$p(x,t+\Delta t) = p + p_t \Delta t + O(\Delta t^2),$$
and
$$p(x\pm \Delta x,t) = p \pm p_x \Delta x + \frac{1}{2} p_{xx} \Delta x^2 \pm \frac{1}{6} p_{xxx} \Delta x^3 + O(\Delta x^4).$$

Therefore

$$\frac{1}{2}(p(x+\Delta x,t) + p(x-\Delta x,t)) =p + \frac{1}{2} p_{xx} \Delta x^2 + O(\Delta x^4).$$

Now equate the largest order terms on both sides. Which term is largest (besides the first term $p$) depends on whether you are scaling like (1) or (2).

Edit: Here are some more details. Equating the Taylor expansions for each side of your equation above we get that

$$p_t \Delta t + O(\Delta t^2) = \frac{1}{2} p_{xx} \Delta x^2 + O(\Delta x^4)$$

as $\Delta t,\Delta x \to 0$. In the first case $\Delta t = \frac{1}{4}\Delta x^2$ and you get

$$p_t = 2 p_{xx} + O(\Delta x^4).$$

Sending $\Delta x \to 0$ you get your heat equation $p_t = 2p_{xx}$. In the second case $\Delta t = \frac{1}{4}\Delta x^3$ and we get

$$p_t \Delta x = 2p_{xx} + O(\Delta x^4).$$

When you send $\Delta x \to 0$ you get $p_{xx}=0$.

Comment: I'm struggling to see how this helps... I'm sorry I know about Taylor Expansions but I don't really get this

Comment: I added some details.